# s3.save a json file to aws s3

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jsonlite

I'm trying to save a correctly formatted json file to aws s3.

I can save a regular data frame to s3 with e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(aws.s3)
s3save(mtcars, bucket = "s3://ourco-emr/", object = "tables/adhoc.db/mtcars/mtcars")
```

But I need to get mtcars into json format. Specifically ndjson.

I am able to create a correctly formatted json file with e.g:

```
predictions_file <- file("mtcars.json")
jsonlite::stream_out(mtcars), predictions_file)
```

This saves a file to my directory called mtcars.json.

However, with the aws.s3 function `s3save()`, I need to send an object that's in memory, not a file.

Tried:

```
predictions_file <- file("mtcars.json")
s3write_using(mtcars, 
              FUN = jsonlite::stream_out,
              con = predictions_file,
              "s3://ourco-emr/", 
              object = "tables/adhoc.db/mtcars/mtcars")
```

Gives:

> Error in if (verbose) message("opening ", is(con), " output connection.") : 
>     argument is not interpretable as logical

I tried the same code block but leaving out the line for con=predictions_file, that just gave:

> Argument con must be a connection.

If the function `jsonlite::stream_out()` creates a correctly formatted json file, how can I then write that file to s3?

Edit:
The desired json output would look like this:

```
{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3,"wt":2,"qsec":16,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3,"wt":2,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":22,"cyl":4,"disp":108,"hp":93,"drat":35,"wt":2,"qsec":18,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":258,"hp":110,"drat":8,"wt":3,"qsec":19,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":18,"cyl":8,"disp":360,"hp":175,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
```

When attempting with readchar:

```
mtcars_string <- readChar("mtcars.json", 1e6)
s3save(mtcars_string, bucket = "s3://ourco-emr/", object = "tables/adhoc.db/mtcars/2020/03/06/mtcars")
```

If I then download and open the resulting json file, it looks like this:

```
5244 5833 0a58 0a00 0000 0300 0306 0000
0305 0000 0000 0555 5446 2d38 0000 0402
0000 0001 0004 0009 0000 000d 6d74 6361
7273 5f73 7472 696e 6700 0000 1000 0000
0100 0400 0900 0012 347b 226d 7067 223a
3231 2c22 6379 6c22 3a36 2c22 6469 7370
```

So it looks like a tsb has been sent to aws s3 as opposed to json

Comment: Can't you just `my_string <- readChar("myfile.json", 1e6)` and `s3save(my_string)`?

Comment: That does seem to allow me to save but the formatting is lost. Feels like it's close. Will add an edit of how the json should appear

Comment: Perhaps you could just use `jsonlite::write_json`?

Comment: @DiceboyT write_json would not format it correctly in nbjson, that's what I tried initially.

Comment: How about `my_raw <- readBin("myjson.json", "raw", 1e6)` and `s3write_using(my_raw, writeBin)` That should be a byte-for-byte copy between disk and s3.

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, same outcome. The data appear more like a tsv after I download, rather than a json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I need to write and upload JSON lines (ndjson) to S3 and, as far as I know, only `stream_out()` from the `jsonlite`-package writes JSON lines.

`stream_out()` takes only connection-objects as a destination, `s3write_using()`, however, writes to a temporary file `tmp` and passes the path to that file as a string to `FUN`. `stream_out()` then throws the error:

> Argument con must be a connection.

A tentative fix is to modify `s3write_using()` to pass a connection to `FUN` instead of a filepath-string.

1. `trace(s3write_using, edit=TRUE)` - opens an editor
2. Change line 5:
   `value <- FUN(x, tmp, ...)`

   To this:
   `value <- FUN(x, file(tmp), ...)`

You can then upload the data using `stream_out()`:

```
s3write_using(x = data, 
              FUN = stream_out,
              bucket = 'mybucket',
              object = 'my/object.json',
              opts = list(acl = "private", multipart = FALSE, verbose = T, show_progress = T))
```

The edit remains for the whole session or until you do `untrace(s3write_using)`.

One should probably file a request in their cloudyr/aws.s3 GitHub as this as to be a common use case.